# How to rename first parameter by .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

How I can rename my 1st parameter to any variable with the help of .htaccess file?

For example, with `http://localhost/mysite/index.php`, I want to rename index.php or any other page name to some specific name.

i.e. .htaccess returns me the following url

`http://localhost/mysite/page`

"page" can be any page name i.e. index.php, about.php, et cetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only 'allow' pages with letters:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^mysite/([a-z]+)$ http://localhost/mysite/$1.php [L]
```

To 'allow' pages with any character

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^mysite/([.]+)$ http://localhost/mysite/$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Mod_rewrite to rewrite your url. This is pattern based.

First add this to your .htaccess

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

this turns on the rewrite engine. Then define a pattern that must be caught & rewritten:

RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/?$ ^.php [L]

I think this rule will do the rewrite you asked. For more info just look on google for examples of mod_Rewrite usage

Answer (score 0):

You would usually have a slug or request URI as part of a query string, and then use a combination of .htaccess and PHP to rewrite that incoming request.

For example, you could couch this in your .htaccess file to catch all incoming requests:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This would re-write any incoming URL that wasn't already a file or directory. So **http://example.com/page** would be matched.

Then in your index.php script, you would have something similar to the following:

```
<?php
$parts = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
```

This just splits your URL at slashes, so if the requested URL were **/page/about-us** you would get an array that looks as follows:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(4) "page"
  [1]=> string(8) "about-us"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

No need  for `htaccess`, use this:

```
RedirectMatch /mysite/index.php http://localhost/mysite/page
```

Comment: no not like this. I want to rename every incoming request to "page" parameter and then on index.php, want to load the page by getting "page" as a query string